# Proving the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{e^x-e^y}{x-y},x\neq y \\\\ 0 \quad\quad\quad ,x=y.\end{cases}$$

This means I have to prove $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{e^x-e^y}{x-y}=0$. But I don't know how to prove it. Could anyone give me hints to proceed it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use maclaurin series ?

Comment: If you take $y=0$, what happens to the limit? And if you take $x=0$? It should help you find the way to prove the general case.

Comment: That function is not continuous at $(0,0)\,.$ You need to fix the case $x=y\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\dfrac{e^x-e^y}{x-y}= e^y\cdot\dfrac{e^{x-y}-1}{x-y} $$

with $x-y\to 0$.

Comment: I know, but does it help?

Comment: This is more a solution than e hint! Do you know standard limit?

Comment: Because I already did like u, but got nothing :(. So the exercise has a problem?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}x$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will help or not

$$e^x-e^y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n-y^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Is that an answer or a question?

Comment: @KurtG. Just a hint. Diving that by $(x-y)$ and taking the limit gives the required result.

Comment: @KurtG. Is it wrong?

Comment: You went from not knowing whether it helps to thinking it might be wrong :) . It is correct and helps but some work is left to do.

Comment: @KurtG. Actually, I don't know whether it is helpful or not because sometimes they need more rigorous proof.